Cube of any integer can be written as the difference of two squares
This exercise is from chapter 1 of Burton's Elementary Number Theory, $7^{th}$ ed which introduces the concept of mathematical induction.
Prove that the cube of any integer can be written as the difference of two squares. [Hint: Notice that $n^3=(1^3+2^3+3^3+\cdots+n^3)-(1^3+2^3+3^3+\cdots+(n-1)^3)$.]
I tried using direct proof where I concluded that $n^3=[\frac{n(n+1)}{2}]^2-[\frac{n(n-1}{2}]^2$ for all $n\geq1$. My question is, considering that the chapter focuses on mathematical induction, would it be possible to use mathematical induction instead of direct proof?
Any help would be highly appreciated.

There is another approach that shows that every perfect power except $4$ can be written as the difference of two squares : It can easily be shown that a positive integer $n>4$ is the difference of two squares iff $n$ is not of the form $4k+2$. If it is of the form $4k+2$ , then we have $2\mid n$ , but $4\nmid n$ showing that $n$ cannot be a perfect power.

The formula you used is typically proven using induction, so I think that your direct argument is fine (as an application of the result of an earlier exercise).

Based on the hint, the induction proof could be to show the $ \sum i^3 = ( \sum i)^2$, though that claim could also be done directly (esp if it's the first time you're seeing it).

Apropos Peter's comment: Any odd number whatsoever can be written as the difference of two squares, and any even number$>4$ that is  $\equiv 0 \bmod 4$ can be written as the difference of two squares. That broader fact leads directly to Peter's observation about perfect powers.

Same question this post
